How to create a Delta Table with local installation of pyspark
I am using a docker image of jupyter/all-spark-notebook, to run my container, which ultimately powers my jupyter notebook by port forwarding
from delta import *
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Delta writer behaviour").getOrCreate()

# just creating dataframe - not to be paid attention
columns = ["Name", "Age"]
data = [("ABC",25),("xyz",27),("zaq",31)]
rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df=rdd.toDF(columns)


# please consider below commented blocks, to be ran one at a time, not simultanioulsy 

# this works
df.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("testp")
reading_after_writing = spark.read.table("testp").show()

# But this do not works
 df.write.format("delta").save("./spark-warehouse/del")
 df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("testd")

Output of df.write.format("delta").save("...")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 df.write.format("delta").save("./spark-warehouse/del")

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:1463, in DataFrameWriter.save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
   1461     self._jwrite.save()
   1462 else:
-> 1463     self._jwrite.save(path)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o432.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: delta. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.dataSourceNotFoundError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:724)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:647)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:240)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: delta.DefaultSource
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:633)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:633)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:633)
    ... 16 more

Output of df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("...")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("testd")

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:1586, in DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(self, name, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
   1584 if format is not None:
   1585     self.format(format)
-> 1586 self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o436.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: delta. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.dataSourceNotFoundError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:724)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:647)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:560)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: delta.DefaultSource
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:633)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:633)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:633)
    ... 15 more

I have tried to install delta libraries, but not working, I am expecting the reason of failure and a permanent fix for the issue, this has always been my reason, why I haven't been preferring my local system for testing

You should check:

Do your image jupyter/all-spark-notebook contains required jars? If not, you should set "spark.jars.packages": "io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.1.0" when you create Spark Session.
Add "spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" and  "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" when you create Spark Session.

You can follow the quickstart here.

Additionally to the other answer we have locally configure_spark_with_delta_pip.
From the delta library function docstring:
Utility function to configure a SparkSession builder such that the generated SparkSession
    will automatically download the required Delta Lake JARs from Maven. This function is
    required when you want to
    
1. Install Delta Lake locally using pip

Example:

from delta import configure_spark_with_delta_pip
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

builder = (
        SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]")
        .appName("pytest-pyspark-local-testing")
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
        .config(
            "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
            "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog",
        )
)

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()



